# How to make banner fullscreen? And adapt to the browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Essentially, I want to put a big banner on my website that would fill the browser as soon as you landed on the page regardless of the browser window size. If the browser window is resized the banner should be able to adapt and still be able to fill the browser window. The banner’s aspect ratio would remain the same, no stretching or shrinking the image as you resize the browser window.

I am new to web development, I just wanted to know what tools I will need to achieve this? And any initial code will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Something very similar to Spotify’s website banner. https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/

***edited***
this is what I have for now, its not much

```
#header_image_div{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#header_image{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you have written so far ?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around on how to make elements responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for

```css
body{ margin:0px 0px; }

#hero{
  background-image:url(https://chrisaam.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/wallpaper-2846361.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  height:100vh;
}

.header{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);  

}

#content{
  padding:100px 50px;
  text-align:center;
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#content h2{
  margin:0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

#footer{
  padding:30px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hero">
    <div class="header">
      <h1> Fullscreen Hero image </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2> If nothing goes right for you , go left.</h2>
    <p> Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p> I am the footer, and you have scroll down to see me.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
    html {
        background: url(path to image file) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Try using the above css declaration which will cover the full browser window and will avoid the stretching of the background image